# Wordpress - change number of displaing images on lowest resolutions

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I've got an online store using woocommerce and storefront. On higher resolutions website displays six images of products in one line. However on mobile phones only one huge picture per line.

This makes my website very difficutl to navigate since I've got 40-60 products per page and scrolling all of them takes a lot of time. I want to display 2-3 pictures on lower resolutions. How can I change it?

Comment: Please post an HTML example. It's mostly the CSS grid configuration.

Comment: If there is no col-small defined, bootstrap will automatically put that col full width (or col-sm-12)